# Celery: "task_revoked" signal not handled after restarting worker

Tags: python, celery

I have a long-running task:

```
from celery import Celery
celery_app = Celery( 'myapp' )

 # ...

@celery_app.task()
def myTask( *args, **kwargs ) :
   # the task body
```

with a `task_revoked` handler attached:

```
from celery.signals import task_revoked

@task_revoked.connect ( sender=myTask, dispatch_uid="myTask" )
def revokeHandler( *args, request=None, **kwargs ) :
   # the handler body
```

The handler works fine, if i start a task and then revoke it normally:

```
job_uuid = myTask.delay( *args, **kwargs )
 # ...
res = AsyncResult( job_uuid )
res.revoke( terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL' )
res.forget()
```

But the handler is **not called** if i first start the task, then restart the celery worker (with the task surviving the restart), and then revoke.

Is there a way to make it work?

Using Celery 4.1.1 with RabbitMQ server 3.2.4 on Python 3.4.3.